# Using an entire font family as fallback font

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I currently have Adobe Garamond Pro as my main font. I would like to use Linux Libertine as a fallback font for missing glyphs.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
    ("ipafallback",
        {
            "[fonts/LinLibertine_R.ttf];",
        }
    )}
\setmainfont{AGaramondPro}[
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    RawFeature={fallback=ipafallback},
]
\newfontfamily{\libertine}{LinLibertine}[
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.ttf,
    UprightFont=*_R,
    BoldFont=*_RB,
    ItalicFont=*_RI,
    BoldItalicFont=*_RBI,
    Scale=MatchLowercase,
]
```

This current setup only uses the upright font as fallback. How can I use the entire `\libertine` font family (e.g., bold, italic, and bold italic), so that the correct font face is selected as dictated by the font switches (e.g., `\bfseries`, `\itshape`)? Bonus if it also scales to `MatchLowercase` of the main font.

Comment: Also, if I were to use Doulos SIL instead which do not have bold and italic faces, how can I use `AutoFakeBold` and `AutoFakeSlant` with `luaotfload.add_fallback`?